# Animating layout height produces weird flicker

Tags: animation, layout

I'm trying to animate a layout (height) placed under the toolbar and inside an AppbarLayout. I have tried several approaches to this: one of them is using ValueAnimator.ofInt and using this int to set the layout's height. This, however, is kind of choppy. According to some posts I've read, it is because requestLayout() is called in each iteration and that's an expensive operation. Almost every other option I've seen requires requestLayout() to be called. Somewhat old devices will not perform well in that case.

The other approach, which apparently is the most efficient, is to simply declare animateLayoutChanges = true in the parent layout (the AppbarLayout in this case) and simply change the height in code. This does work, but it produces and weird jump, as if the layout instantly and very breifly goes to it's final height, collapses again, and then starts animating normally. The same happens when collapsing.

In the activity, I'm simply calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to expand and newTaskLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) to collapse. I've also tried setting height to 0 and then making the view GONE to collapse, and setting height to wrap content and then making the view VISIBLE to expand, but the result is the same.

Is there any reason for this and way to avoid it? Or is there a better way to do it?

**Heres the XML:** (The view being animated is the COnstraintLayout under the toolbar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.adrapps.mytasks.Views.TaskListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:title="App"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_task_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="164dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_label"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_edit_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/title_edit_text"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/date_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_date"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/date_edit_text"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/date_edit_text"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_none_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/date_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_icon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/title_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/task_title_hint"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title_icon"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/date_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:hint="@string/task_due_date"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/date_icon"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/date_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_edit_text" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/notification_spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:entries="@array/notification_options"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/notification_icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/notification_icon"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/notification_icon" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```